# Solidity Error :: ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'Number'

Tags: parsing, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Hiii, I need help
Getting parser error here in the line
require(msg.value > o.1 ether);

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
  pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Lottery{
address public manager;
address[] public players;

constructor(){
    manager=msg.sender;
}

function enter() public payable{
   
    require(msg.value > o.1 ether);  //getting error here
    players.push(msg.sender);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, using the letter `o` instead of the number `0`.

Corrected line:

```
require(msg.value > 0.1 ether);
```